# Justify that a point z is a boundary point of A

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We know that $x_n$ and $y_n$ both converge to a point $z$.

Let's suppose that $A\subset$ $\mathbb{R^p}$ such that for every $n$$\in$$\mathbb{N}$, $x_n$$\in$$A$ and $y_n$$\notin$$A$.
Show that $z$ is a boundary point of $A$.

We know that $x_n$ is a converging sequence and that $\forall$$n$$\in$$\mathbb{N}$,$x_n$$\in$$A$, so $A$ is closed.

Now that I know that A is closed what can I do ?

Comment: You do not know that $A$ i sclosed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $x_n\to z$, we know $z\in\overline A$. From $y_n\to z$, we know $z\in \overline{A^\complement}$. Hence $z\in \overline A\cap \overline{A^\complement}=\partial A$.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is an open set that contains $z$ then for $n$ large enough we will have $x_n,y_n\in U$, showing that $U\cap A$ and $U\cap A^{\complement}$ are not empty.

This for *every* open set that contains $z$.

This means exactly that $z$ is a boundary point of $A$ (i.e. is element of the closure of $A$ and also of the closure of $A^{\complement}$).